# Ubuntu One startup on Mac

Tags: ubuntu-one, startup, macosx

Ubuntu One is installed on my MacBook, OS X Lion, and appears to be working fine, other than it does not appear to load automatically at startup.

Please note that **Connect automatically when computer starts** is selected.

Is there a way to set this up, other than including it as a **Login item** under the **User & Groups** in **System Preferences**? Which is what I have implemented in the interim. (I have **Hide** ticked so that one does not see the Ubuntu One gui pop up every time one logs in).

But I suspect that there may be a more elegant way of implementing the Ubuntu One start up.

Comment: +1 I have exactly the same problem. I have also set it as a login item as a workaround.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted to be closed by a couple people as a duplicate of "Is there an Ubuntu One for OSX?" but it is certainly not a duplicate of it. @netsurfer38 have you tried to disable/re-enable the "load automatically at startup" option in Ubuntu One, to see if it will then work afterword?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to disable/re-enable the "load automatically at startup", have tried it, but unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the confusion. So, this is actually two bugs.

First, the preference box is labelled confusingly wrong. It does not mean "start syncing when you log into your computer". It means "start syncing when the Ubuntu One background sync program starts". The Ubuntu One background sync program, called `ubuntuone-syncdaemon`, is intended to be running all the time, and this preference is for people who want to manually control when it uses the network. I recommend you keep it on.

Second, the mac client does not currently add itself to the login items list, so it will not start at login unless you add it there manually. Adding it manually is exactly the right way to solve your problem, because that is all that a fixed version will do anyway.